# is there anyway to change properties of textlengthlimit indicator in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I just want to take the input text counter  and max length inside text form field

```
TextFormField(
              controller: newusrname, //u can ignore this controller
              maxLength: 30,       //this is the limit i have set           
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                labelText: "Username",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
              ),
            ),
```

[image: Here is my attached image]

Comment: please share your source code

Comment: its just textformfield brother...still i have edited the post with one of my textformfield code...You can see the output of this code in attached image...see if you can help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this

```
  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
  String text = ""; // empty string to carry what was there before it

  int maxLength = 30;
TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                labelText: "Username",
                suffix: Text("${_controller.text.length}/$maxLength"),
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
              ),
                onChanged: (String newVal) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (newVal.length <= maxLength) {
                      text = newVal;
                    } else {
                      _controller.value = new TextEditingValue(
                          text: text,
                          selection: new TextSelection(
                              baseOffset: maxLength,
                              extentOffset: maxLength,
                              affinity: TextAffinity.downstream,
                              isDirectional: false),
                          composing: new TextRange(start: 0, end: maxLength));
                      _controller.text = text;
                    }
                  });
                },

            ),
```

Comment: wow bro this worked!!! Can you plz explain what you did here so I can improve it more and I can learn something new...any reference will be also okay like video, blog or anything or your own explanation...And Thanks a lot bro!!!

Comment: In onchanged method, I just carried out the text length with setState and put it into the suffix widget that's it

Comment: awesome! Its just around 1 week since i started learning Flutter so its totally new for me I guess and also I haven't even mastered any other languages. Thanks again for help!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the text length indicator’s position using the default `TextFormField`. However, you could build your own text length indicator widget and place it besides the text field, for example. Though, this still won’t allow you to place it inside.

Comment: ohh man..this just ruining my UI. Lets see what can I do or I will wait for any other useful answer here! anyway Thanks!